# ISO8601DateFormatter - setting format options

Tags: swift

I have just started working with dates in Swift(UI) and am having some issues with the format options on the ISO8601DateFormatter.

I am using date/time strings retrieved from a mysql database example: "2021-07-31T18:00:00Z"

and the following swift code in a struct:

```
    private var dueDate:String
var due: Date {
    let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime,
    .withDashSeparatorInDate,
    .withColonSeparatorInTime,
    .withColonSeparatorInTimeZone,
    .withFullTime
    ]
    return(formatter.date(from: dueDate)!)
}
```

when used in a view with:

```
Text("\(task.due)")
```

I'm getting the entire date printed like -
[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction to be able to format the date to something like "Wednesday, July 14th"?

Comment: Is `due` not nil? I mean is String in Database with ISO8601DateFormatter to Date working? If yes, for the next one, use another formatter not a ISO one.

Comment: You can try for instance `df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEEE MMMM dd yyyy, HH:mm:ss zzzz")`, or something like that, more info at http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns ?

Comment: in teh database it is a date/time object, retrieved with "DATE_FORMAT(tasks.dueDate, '%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') AS dueDate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and am having some issues with the format options on the ISO8601DateFormatter

No you're not. The ISO8601DateFormatter is working perfectly and is doing just what you want it to do: it is turning a string "2021-07-31T18:00:00Z" into a date `due`. It does that and then its job is done and it is destroyed.

As for what appears in the Text, that is a completely different matter. Now you want to turn a date into a string. For that you need *another* formatter, a second one, a DateFormatter. You don't have one so you are subject to the whim of the system. If you don't like that, create that second  formatter and format the date into a string that looks the way you want.

Comment: Cheers for that -  I was assuming the ISOFormatter did this with it's options - bit murky there but problem all solved.